# Universal Links while app is not running

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, ios-universal-links

I am implementing Universal Links in my app. Every things works for me, except when the app is not running in the background. In that case how i can open a specific page in my app? iOS launches my app but i am not getting any callback in

`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *))restorationHandler`
in this function neither i am getting any url with this line

`NSURL *launchURL = [launchOptions valueForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey];` 
inside

`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` this function.

Does anybody have an idea how i can get the url which caused to launch my application.

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain  Every things works for me ? What is not working for you ?

Comment: didFinishLaunching will not get called when your app is in background. You should look into openURL method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open a Universal Link with your app

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app
        openURL:(NSURL *)url
        options:(NSDictionary<NSString *,
                         id> *)options
```

is called with the Universal Link as a parameter and options if it is the case. Check [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:openURL:options:) for details.

Comment: It does not answer the question. This delegate method is called whenever the user clicks on a deeplink. We don't know if the app is already launched or not.

Answer (score 2):

You can access to your url in this way ...

```
    NSDictionary *aux = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsUserActivityDictionaryKey];
    if (aux) {
         NSUserActivity *activity = [aux objectForKey:@"UIApplicationLaunchOptionsUserActivityKey"];
         NSString *urlString = activity.webpageURL.absoluteString;
    }
```

But for better use you have to validate this URL and return YES if you can manage it

For example ...

```
if([urlString hasPrefix:@"https://myUrl.com"]) {
  return YES;
}
```

.. after this the method

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *))restorationHandler
```

It will be called

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 5 with a `SceneDelegate` file it will call:

```
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) { }
```

When your app is NOT running in background and user clicks on a universal link.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application  openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation{

   url= yourappurl://with some app link data
   sourceApplication= //who called your application

  }
```

For example if your app is called from facebook messenger, then you will get

```
  sourceApplication=@"com.facebook.messenger"
```