# Opening an app from another one to a specific VC

Tags: ios, swift, ios-universal-links

I'm pretty new to iOS dev and I didn't find any concrete answer.

Let's say I have an app with 2 targets, FirstApp (firstTarget) and SecondApp (secondTarget).  I saw in some posts that you can open an app from another and I did do that with:

```
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(aUrl as! URL) {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(aUrl!)
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
```

But can I open it to a specific VC in SecondApp?

I included UniversalLink in my project and also the AppDelegate method with an alert in it:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    print("UNIVERSAL LINK")
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Test", message:"Message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
    self.window?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    return true
}
```

The thing is, it's only working after I repeat the action 1 more time. For the first time it's only opening the app. If I go back on the FirstApp and repeat the action then the alert pops up.

Can I do it in another way or do you have a solution for this way?

Doesn't the notification work the same way? When I click on it, it redirects you to a specific VC.

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
    let noNetworkView = UIView()
    var reachability:Reachability!

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        return SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Test", message:"Message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        self.window?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        return true
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
        return SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, open: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, handleOpen url: URL) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        self.reachability.stopNotifier()
        self.saveContext()
    }
```

Comment: Can you see any log ? . looks like your `self.window?.rootViewController` is not ready to show alert. You can store some bool variable in your userdefault when this function executes and from your rootviewcontroller check that bool and show alert

Comment: Sorry, I'm not getting it  :D.. i can't see any log btw and as I said the alert it's showing only the second time once the app is already opened.. Function? You mean the appDelegate one? it will do the same i think cause this is triggered only the second time as well

Comment: when first time this method call there might be `self.window?.rootViewController` is nil so it is not showing alert while second time your app in background so `self.window?.rootViewController` is not nil. so you can see alert.

Comment: Can you provide the full code of your `AppDelegate`

Comment: @Hodson , If you need anything else just tell me. I also had the Core Data part but i dont think was necessary

Comment: I've managed to do it. DidFinishLaunching was returning me false all the time thats why it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`continueUserActivity` is not called on app launch. You will have to pull the Universal Link out of the launch options on `didFinishLaunchingOptions`. See this [post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36283423/universal-links-while-app-is-not-running) I recommend using [Branch](https://docs.branch.io) since they will bundle this all up into one callback for you.